# Array / Snapping Help

Tags: modifiers, snapping

I've been trying to model a tire recently and got stuck trying to create the tread. I added an array modifier to my tread and set the object offset to an empty I used for the rotation. I ended up with this. It turns just enough to not fit the tire and starts going in a different direction. What would I do to fix this? Did I snap something wrong? I had everything set to the center, what could possibly be causing this? Thanks for any help!

PS I added an extra picture. The bottom picture shows what happens when I add in a brand new empty without changing the rotation yet, the tread seems to start going a different way and also the tread arrayed starts from the bottom which I'm not used to. That is a 100 count in the bottom picture.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Without looking at your file, it's hard to tell. But if I have to guess I think you might have moved / rotated the empty slightly to much (and possible on the incorrect axis) from the origin of the tread object. I would guess you only need to rotate the empty a couple of degrees on the z-axis but nothing more and no movement / scaling.

Comment: There may also be a small relative offset in your array modifier, leading to skewed results